# Diagonal operator and infinite wedge space formalism

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, gromov-witten-theory, enumerative-geometry

Let $\bigwedge^{\infty /2}V$ denote semiinfinte wedge space. The followin article section 2 gives a good description about the space and the operator on it. 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0207233.pdf

Using the notation from the article $v_{\lambda}$ form the basis of $\bigwedge^{\infty /2}V$. With respect to this basis there is a inner product defined

$$ \langle v_{\lambda},v_{\lambda'}\rangle =\delta_{\lambda,\lambda'} .$$

For an operator  $M$ on $\bigwedge^{\infty /2}V\rightarrow \bigwedge^{\infty /2}V$, the expectation is defined as

$$ \langle M v_{\phi},v_{\phi}\rangle    .$$ where $v_{\phi}$ is the vaccum vector defined as $v_{\phi}:=-1/2\wedge -3/2\wedge -5/2\ldots$

With respect to this basis, we say an operator $D$ is diagonal if 
$$ Dv_{\lambda}=c_{\lambda}v_{\lambda}$$ where $c_{\lambda}$ is a scalar.

Lets define the following fundamental operator on the wedge space

$E_{k,k}v_{S}=v_{S},\ if k>0,k\in S$ or $E_{k,k}v_{S}=v_{S},\ if k,0,k\notin S$ or 0 otherwise.

Few examples of operator given in the notes are Charge operator, Engergy operator etc.

The following diagonal operator noted by $F$ and defined as

$$F v_{\lambda}=\frac{C_{2,1,1\ldots,1}}{dim \lambda}\chi_{2,1,\ldots,1}^{\lambda}v_{\lambda} $$
where $C_{2,1,1\ldots,1}$ denote the size of conjugancy class of type $(2,1,\ldots,1)$ in the symmetric group $S_{|\lambda|}$,$\chi$ is the character. 
Using Frobenius identity it can be shown that

$$F=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}+1/2}\frac{k^{2}}{2 } E_{k,k} $$

Is there a reference of the above result in general case? What I mean by general is the fact that I change the scalar in the definition of $F$ that is change $\frac{C_{2,1,1\ldots,1}}{dim \lambda}\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}$. For example I want the following operator expressed in terms of $E_{kk}$.

$$F'v_{\lambda}= \frac{C_{2,2,\ldots,2}}{dim \lambda}\chi_{2,2\ldots,2}^{\lambda}v_{\lambda}$$ 
is there any way to represent it in terms of $E_{kk}$. What about replacing 
$C_{2,2,\ldots,2}$ with other partion of $|\lambda|$ etc?

Comment: "...$D$ is diagonal if $Dv_{\lambda}=c v_{\lambda}$". I imagine you meant a $c_\lambda$ right?